# nuxt multiple deployment with same build

Tags: nuxt.js

I need to deploy the same nuxt build (production mode) on multiple servers. Problem is that we using nuxt/apollo, so need different graphql endpoints for each server. I am aware we can use .env but that will mean building separately for each deployment (which I do not want to do).

Is there any way we can achieve this (like for nuxt/axios we can use absolute URLs directly rather then the configured ones) ?